Access properties of child class in base class array
I want to access child class properties that only exist in the child class in an array of type base class
(changed the example from animal to question)
class Survey
{

Question[] questions

}

class Question
{

string question
bool required
}

class ChoiceQuestion: Question
{

AnswerOptions[] answerOptions
bool isMultiple

}

class FreeTextQuestion: Question
{
} 

Survey survey = new Survey()
Question[] questions = [new FreeTextQuestion(), new ChoiceQuestion())]
survey.questions = questions

Now when I loop through the animal array and I want to access the specific information to do something with it. I could use instanceof like this:
foreach(Question question in questions)
{

  if(question is FreeTextQuestion)
  {
   FreeTextQuestion freeTextQuestion = question as FreeTextQuestion
  }
  else if (a is ChoiceQuestion)
  {
   ChoiceQuestion choiceQuestion = question as ChoiceQuestion
  }
}

But I read that casting like this is not polymorpism so I shouldnt use it but I dont see another option and i need the information what type the question is to for expample store the question in the right database table

It depends on the thing you want to do with.

when i need the information as a variable and not a string so what should i do?  what does this really mean?

This depend on what you want or need to do. The basic idea with polymorphism is that you should not need to know the derived class:
public interface IAnimal{
    string Sound {get;}
}
public Dog : IAnimal{
    public string Sound => "Woof";
}
public Cat : IAnimal{
    public string Sound => "Meow"
}

If you have some code that needs to access cat/dog specific properties, move that code to the classes instead. I.e. add a method to the interface or abstract method, with separate implementations for cats and dogs.
Ofc, this is not always practical. Pattern matching as you demonstrate is a common workaround, but it is not clear from your example if it is appropriate or not. A downside with pattern matching if that you need to consider all the places that need to change if you add or remove a new animal.
Another possibility is the visitor pattern. This can help separate your animal model, from other concerns like, serialization. And it can help with generating compiler errors if a specific type of animal is not handled somewhere.

if i want to render the list of animals i would need access to the animal specific properties that only exist in that animal show all information on screen

@KilianReichart If you simply want to list animals in a UI you could have properties like Name, Species etc, for whatever columns you want to show. Or possibly have a property like IEnumerable<(string PropertyName, string Value)>. In some cases you might want to create one UI control per type of animal, and use visitors to map the animal to the corresponding control.

ok i will change the example to better suit my question
